# How to open multiple text files into one excel sheet but skip line 1 for each text file?

Tags: excel, file, vba, text, import

With the code below I am able to open all text files in my folder into one excel sheet. Each file has headers and what I cant figure out is how to have it skip the first line in each text file.

```
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim folder As folder
Dim file As file
Dim FileText As TextStream
Dim TextLine As String
Dim Items() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim cl As Range

' Get a FileSystem object
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
' get the directory you want
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("\\mydirectoryfolderhere")
' set the starting point to write the data to
Set cl = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
' Loop thru all files in the folder
For Each file In folder.Files
' Open the file
Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

' Read the file one line at a time
Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
TextLine = FileText.ReadLine
' Parse the line into | delimited pieces
Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
' Put data on one row in active sheet
For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
cl.Offset(1, i).Value = Items(i)
Next
'Move to next row
Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

' Clean up
FileText.Close
Next file

Set FileText = Nothing
Set file = Nothing
Set folder = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
Dim firstline as boolean
'.....
For Each file In folder.Files
Set FileText = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
firstline=True

Do While Not FileText.AtEndOfStream
    TextLine = FileText.ReadLine

    If Not firstline then

        Items = Split(TextLine, "|")
        For i = 0 To UBound(Items)
            cl.Offset(1, i).Value = Items(i)
        Next
        Set cl = cl.Offset(1, 0)

    End If

    firstline=False
Loop

' Clean up
FileText.Close
Next file
'....
```